# How to publish a laravel site on github?

Tags: laravel, github-pages

How to publish a laravel site on github? I have a laravel site repo stored on github but I want to publish it as website on github. Possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. Github pages doesn't support PHP. It can host only static websites: HTML, CSS, Javascript.